# tikz-uml delete object in sequence diagram

Tags: tikz-uml

I hope someone can help me. I created an object with tikz-uml. Jet I want to delete it, but I have no clue how. I want an synchron arrow, like the one on create, and then an "x" on the lifeline of the object. This example code should end with delete on an "x" at the lifeline of b.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgfopts}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlobject[class=A]{a}
\umlcreatecall [ class=B] {a}{b}
\begin{umlcall}
[op={function()},dt=6, type=synchron, return={return}]{a}{b}
\end{umlcall}
\begin{umlcall}
[op={delete}, dt=4, type=synchron, ]{a}{b}
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide us with a *complete* minimal example, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you.
Paste this modified code into the file "tikz-uml.sty" in the last line.

```
\newenvironment{umlcallKill}[3][]
{
    \stepcounter{tikzumlCallNum}
    \edef\tikzumlCall@lastchildNum{\thetikzumlCallNum}
    \gdef\tikzumlCallBottom{0}
    \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/call/.cd, 
            dt/.initial=\tikzumlCallDefaultDT, 
            name/.initial={call-\thetikzumlCallNum},
                        op/.initial={},
                        .unknown/.code=
                        {
                            \let\keyname=\pgfkeyscurrentname
                                \let\keyvalue=\pgfkeyscurrentvalue
                                \errmessage{TIKZUML ERROR : in umlcallKill,  invalid option \keyname}
                        }
    }
    \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/call/.cd, #1}
    \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/call/.cd, dt/.get=\tikzumlCallDT, op/.get=\tikzumlCallOp}
  
    \let\tikzumlCallStartNodeNameold\tikzumlCallStartNodeName
    \def\tikzumlCallStartNodeName{#2}
    \let\tikzumlCallEndNodeNameold\tikzumlCallEndNodeName
    \def\tikzumlCallEndNodeName{#3}
    \edef\tikzumlCall@parent{}
    \edef\tikzumlCall@parentold{}
    \edef\tikzumlCall@nameold{}
    \edef\tikzumlCall@name{call-\thetikzumlCallNum}

    \begingroup
    \def\_{_}\edef\x{\endgroup
        \def\noexpand\tikzumlCall@nodeName{\tikzumlCall@name}}\x
    \let\tikzumlCall@nodeNameold\tikzumlCall@nodeName
    % top node of activity period of call sender
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{connections}
        \pgfmathparse{\tikzumlCallDT}
        \draw (\csname tikzumlLastChild@\tikzumlCallStartNodeName \endcsname)+(0,-\pgfmathresult ex) node[coordinate, name=tikzumlTmpNode] {};
        \node[tikzuml activity style] (st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) at (\tikzumlCallStartNodeName |- tikzumlTmpNode) {};
        % update last node drawn on sender lifeline
        \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlLastChild@\tikzumlCallStartNodeName \endcsname{st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}
        \node[tikzuml activity style, draw=none] (et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) at (\tikzumlCallEndNodeName |- st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) {};
        % update last node drawn on receiver lifeline
        \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlLastChild@\tikzumlCallEndNodeName \endcsname{et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}
        \xdef\tikzumlCallBottomSrc{et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}%
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \stepcounter{tikzumlCallLevel}
}{
    \addtocounter{tikzumlCallLevel}{-1}
    % bottom nodes of activity periods of call sender and receiver
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{connections}
            \draw (\tikzumlCallBottomSrc)+(0, -0.2 ex) node[coordinate, name=tikzumlTmpNode] {};
            \node[cross out, draw=black, line width=1pt, minimum size=12pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (eb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) at (\tikzumlCallEndNodeName |- tikzumlTmpNode) {};
            \node[tikzuml activity style] (sb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) at (\tikzumlCallStartNodeName |- eb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) {};
            \xdef\tikzumlCallBottomSrc{sb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    % draw activity periods
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{activity}
            % draw root activity period
            \draw[draw=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, fill=\tikzumlCallDefaultFillColor] (st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.north west) rectangle (sb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.south east);
            % Do not draw receiver activity period
            \draw[draw=none] (et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.north west) rectangle (eb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.south east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    % update last nodes drawn on sender and receiver lifelines
    \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlLastChild@\tikzumlCallEndNodeName \endcsname{eb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}
    \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlLastChild@\tikzumlCallStartNodeName \endcsname{sb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}
    % draw call arrows
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{connections}
            \pgfextractx{\tikzumlCall@xa}{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzumlCallStartNodeName}{center}}
            \pgfextractx{\tikzumlCall@xb}{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzumlCallEndNodeName}{center}}
            \ifthenelse{\tikzumlCall@xb>\tikzumlCall@xa}
            {
                \draw[tikzuml synchron-msg style, \tikzumlDefaultDrawColor] (st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.east) -- (et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.west) 
                node[font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, text=\tikzumlDefaultTextColor, midway, above=-0.4ex, name=\tikzumlCall@nodeName-op] {\tikzumlCallOp};
            }
            {
                \draw[tikzuml synchron-msg style, \tikzumlDefaultDrawColor] (st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.west) -- (et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.east) 
                node[font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, text=\tikzumlDefaultTextColor, midway, above=-0.4ex, name=\tikzumlCall@nodeName-op] {\tikzumlCallOp};
            }
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}
```

Now you can call the needed solution as follows:

```
\begin{umlcallKill}[dt=3,op={functionName()}]{instanceNameSrc}{instanceNameDes}
\end{umlcallKill}
```

It is important that you only enter "dt=" and "op={}", but you must specify them. What does not work are self-calls.
Then you will get the following:

[image: Example image]

Example code:

```
\documentclass[border=1]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
        \tikzumlset{fill object = white, fill call = gray!20} 
        \begin{umlseqdiag}
            % class instances
            \umlobject[class=A]{a}
            \umlobject[class=B]{b}
            
            \begin{umlcallKill}[dt=3,op={functionName()}]{a}{b}
            \end{umlcallKill}
            
        \end{umlseqdiag}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Changing an original file is not an good idea. Copy it, rename it, change it and use it with the new name ...

Comment: I will try to pay attention to this in the future. Thanks for the hint!